# Postgres functions: how to pass a type as an argument

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am using this query to list the values that are part of an enum:

```sql
SELECT unnest(enum_range(null::my_enum_name)) AS enum_values;
```

It works.

I am trying to make it more reusable by wrapping it in a function that takes the name of the enum (`my_enum_name` in the example above) as a parameter, but I can't find a lot of documentation on this.

Is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried creating a function? Did you encounter any errors? Why wouldn't it be possible? Welcome to DBA.SE.

Comment: Hi, thank you @Johnakahot2use. I've tried to type the parameter with [`regtype`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-oid.html), but couldn't find a way to use it to cast `null` in the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible:

```
create type mood as enum ('sad','ok', 'happy');
CREATE TYPE

create function f(p_typname text) returns setof text 
as $$
begin
   return query execute 
      format(
         'SELECT unnest(enum_range(null:: %s))::text AS enum_values',
         p_typname
      );
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION

select * from f('mood');
   f   
-------
 sad
 ok
 happy
(3 rows)
```