# How do you run "SELECT" on the composite type argument of an SQL function?

Tags: postgresql, functions, postgresql-13, record

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/bCSwVpd9

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE entities (
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TYPE entity_id AS (
  id bigint
);
```

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_entities (
  pagination_limit bigint DEFAULT 25,
  pagination_offset bigint DEFAULT 0,
  entity_ids entity_id DEFAULT NULL
)
RETURNS TABLE (
  id bigint
)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $BODY$
  WITH input_entities AS (
    SELECT
      id
    FROM
      entities
    WHERE
      -- filter by id list if provided
      entity_ids IS NULL OR id IN (
        SELECT
          id
        FROM
          entity_ids
      )
    ORDER BY
      id ASC
    LIMIT pagination_limit
    OFFSET pagination_offset
  )
  SELECT
    id
  FROM
    input_entities
  ORDER BY
    id
$BODY$;
```

The crutch is I want to write a paginated multi-select function which could work both from pagination info and a set of ids. The problem with the function above it crashes with:

```sh
ERROR:  relation "entity_ids" does not exist
LINE 22:           entity_ids
```

There are similar responses to this problem: [first](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/263986/259283), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56753558/14481500). However they revolve around argument being an identifier string, not a composite record type and also use `plpgsql`, which might or might nor be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question title and question body ask different questions, so I will address both.

**As respects the question title:** You don't need to `SELECT` against a composite type, you can reference fields in it directly using dot notation. For example, if your type is defined as

```
CREATE TYPE entity_id AS (
  id bigint,
  name text
);
```

and an instance of the type is passed to a function with an argument named `foo`, you can reference the fields as `foo.id` and `foo.text`, respectively.

**As respects the question body:** You can't pass a recordset as a function argument, but you can convert it to an array and pass that. In your case, use an array as the `id` list argument, and the `= ANY` operator to search it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_entities(pagination_limit bigint DEFAULT 25, pagination_offset bigint DEFAULT 0, entity_ids bigint[] DEFAULT NULL)
 RETURNS TABLE(id bigint)
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
  WITH input_entities AS (
    SELECT
      id
    FROM
      entities
    WHERE
      entity_ids IS NULL OR id = ANY ( entity_ids )
    ORDER BY
      id ASC
    LIMIT pagination_limit
    OFFSET pagination_offset
  )
  SELECT
    id
  FROM
    input_entities
  ORDER BY
    id
$function$
```

Call like:

```
SELECT * FROM get_entities(25,0,ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]::bigint[]);
```

Or to use the output of a subquery, use the `ARRAY()` constructor:

```
SELECT * FROM get_entities(25,0,ARRAY(SELECT ids FROM mytable ...));
```

Since you wanted to see how to pass a recordset from a table-valued function to another:

```
SELECT * FROM get_entities(25,0,ARRAY(SELECT id FROM myfunc());
```

Of course, the constructor is unnecessary if `myfunc()` returns an array.

The two ideas expressed above can be combined; you can have an array of composite type instances.

Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/arrays.html

Comment: I specifically wanted to avoid making it an array because then every function like this has to transform it into a record and the consumer has to transform the record into an array for each function like this.
I don't follow on your generated identity column comment. As far as types concerned `id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY` is just column of type `bigint`, it being an identity is a domain/constraint detail. So my idea was that consumers can just `SELECT id FROM tablename/temp_tablename` and pass it as an argument to the function.

Comment: Okay, turns out it's not possible to have a table/recordset as an argument to a function.
So add a `create_entities()` function your answer which invokes `get_entities()` on the final set (to show how it is supposed to work within queries) and I'll accept your answer.
For the reference see https://dbfiddle.uk/nBffoDMj

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand what you want me to do… you want me to copy your create_entities() function from your fiddle into my answer? Your fiddle looks correct.

Comment: Either copy or write your own which would add entities and then pass the IDs of newly created entities as an array to the `get_entities()` instead of just `RETURNING`. This will show how to pass the array argument from the set of records and that functions are composable.

Comment: I added some additional information to the answer.

Comment: How do you use the array of composites though? [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) assumes a multidimensional array for its multicolumn syntax.

Comment: An array of a composite type is still a 1-D array. If you want to go into detail on usage, ask a new question. Comments are not for extended discussion.